# How to return a usercontrol to the Mainwindow from ViewModel WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have a `MainWindow`, when a button is pressed a methode in my `ViewModel` gets called.

```
public void BtnOpenClick()
{
     //DoStuff
     VideoControl mediaplayer = new VideoControl
}
```

which instantiats a new `Videocontrol` from my views which is a usercontrol written in some `XAML`.

My question is how can I return a `usercontrol` from the `ViewModel` back to the `MainWindow` in `MVVM` way?

**Edit**

I had a misunderstanding off the MVVM Pattern and what I was trying to do clearly violates the pattern.

For now I have a solution In the Mainwindow I bind to my usercontrol (VideoControl)

```
<StackPanel>
    <Local:VideoControl IconInfos="{Binding SourceVideos}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

My ViewModel looks Like this

```
class VideoControlViewModel : ViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Video> _Videos;

    public ObservableCollection<Video> Videos
    {
        get { return _Videos; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Videos, value); }
    }
}
```

My Model is just the Uri of the File I want to play in my MediaElement

```
public class Video
{
    public Uri FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Than in the usercontrol I have a datatemplate and Some More XAML

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="VideoTemplate">
        <MediaElement x:Name="MediaPlayer" Source="{Binding FileName }"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Videos}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource VideoTemplate}"
                          Grid.Row="1">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </StackPanel>
```

And in the Code Behind I have this code

```
VideoControlViewModel _vm;

public VideoControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _vm = (VideoControlViewModel) VideoGrid.DataContext;
}

public ObservableCollection<Video> IconInfos
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<Video>)GetValue(IconInfosProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IconInfosProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty IconInfosProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("IconInfos", typeof(ObservableCollection<Video>),
       typeof(VideoControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnIconInfosSet));

private static void OnIconInfosSet(DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((VideoControl)d)._vm.Videos = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<Video>;
}
```

For Now when I call a button I can add another Item to the Obeservable collection and a mediaplayer will pop up on the main window with the selected Uri.

Comment: This seems like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you really want to do?

Comment: There is no MVVM whatsoever about "returning a usercontrol from the ViewModel back to the MainWindow".' A view model doesn't create controls.

Comment: @mm8 I'm not really sure about this. In what way does my answer violate MVVM?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé: I haven't commented your answer. I was commenting the question. But a view model should still not create an instance of a control. This clearly violates the MVVM pattern.

Comment: @mm8 I know, but I think creating controls in the ViewModel is no violation of MVVM. The way I did it should be ok, or not?

Comment: In that case I would rethink my approach. thank u for the answers

Comment: "how can I return a usercontrol from the ViewModel back to the MainWindow in MVVM way" lol @RomanoZumbé UI logic in your VM is a clear violation of MVVM.  It's also a very common misunderstanding of new mvvm developers. They often think NO CODEBEHIND whereas MVVM is really about separating UI concerns from business and application logic.  And, even then, you have to remember the pattern serves us, not the other way around. So sometimes your answer may be appropriate. Not now, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass your control to the content:

```
    public void BtnOpenClick()
    {
         //DoStuff
         VideoControl mediaplayer = new VideoControl();

         MainWindow.YourControl.Content = mediaplayer;
    }
```